# Strange Graetz Bridge Output

Tags: resistors, charge, bridge

Playing with electronics I discovered a strange behaviour of a Graetz bridge. This is my scheme: 
[image]

The corresponding output looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why I have a additional peak once a period.

When I add a charge, in my case a resistor as shown in the following scheme, the output looks like learned at school:
[image]
[image]

Does anybody know, why this behaviour occurs?

Comment: I think that two of those diodes (top left and bottom left) are not correctly orientated.

Answer (score 2):

Without a load on the bridge, the oscilloscope input capacitance charges to a peak voltage on one half cycle of the AC and barely discharges because the only resistive load is the o-scope input impedance and this is very high.

I can't explain why the waveform is the peculiar shape rather than being a flat line at some positive voltage but it's possibly due self capacitance of the diodes in the bridge.

Comment: My guess about the particular shape is that it is due to the scope's power supply drawing more current on an alternation of the mains than on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why you're getting anything at all, much less the results you are seeing. Please change your bridge - it is wrong. The two left-hand diodes are the wrong polarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3sGRB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You're right, the scheme was wrong. I changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Together with the input capacity the scheme is a resonant circuit for about the third harmonic. The resistor absorbs the energy.

Comment: This is pretty short for an answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question as it was asked. Please add details to your answers, such as how and why it works or is the correct answer. Single-line shallow answers are subject to downvotes or deletion.